# .htaccess Rewrite Rules conflict

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a `.htaccess` file written as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?([^/.]+)$ display.php?category=$1 [B,L] 
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/.]+)/?$ gallery.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([-_\+A-Za-z0-9,]+)$ displayitem.php?item=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ displayitem.php?item=$1&start=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
```

The problem occurs while displaying the `displayitem.php?item=$1`. When I try to execute this command, the page will stay on previous page and the `displayitem.php` will not be found.

This is weird. If I comment out the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^/.]+)$ display.php?category=$1 [B,L]
```

which is used to pass utf-8 character, everything works fine and all the rules will be executed and all the parameters will be passed. However, utf-8 character will not be passed correctly and echo Page Not found.

Please help!! Thanks.

Comment: `^/?([^/.]+)$` matches a lot of things. It certainly matches anything that `^([-_+A-Za-z0-9,]+)$` also matches. You have to make the regexp tighter to avoid the collision.

Comment: Hi Rafa, thank you for your reply. I am a newbie to regexp. How can I make it tighter to avoid the conflict?